# pcap_next() returns non-existent bytes?

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I'm being very puzzled by an output returned by pcap_next(). It consistently returns a mysterious "C5" byte under certain conditions. When I compare the output of that function with an output form Wireshark the "C5" is not there.

```
while( 1 ) {
    packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
    if( packet == 0 ) {
        continue;
    }

    printf( "Captured: %d %d\n\n", header.caplen, header.len );
    _rtmp_print_buff( packet, header.caplen );
    printf( "\n\n-------------------\n\n");
```

// (....)

```
void _rtmp_print_buff( const u_char *buff, int size ) {
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
        if( i % 16 == 0 ) printf(  "\n" );
        printf( "%02X ", (u_char) *(buff+i));
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Part of the packet from Wireshark looks like this:

```
2000   56 b3 7a d7 81 4c c3 **24 ee** 63 57 32 77 24 bd 55
2010   48 c1 94 4c ad e9 a2 8c 90 59 25 ad 94 69 f2 69
```

The same data returned by _rtmp_print_buff()

```
3C D7 55 27 D7 1C 64 2F CE F0 AC 0C 8C 56 B3 7A
D7 81 4C C3 24 **C5** EE 63 57 32 77 24 BD 55 48 C1
94 4C AD E9 A2 8C 90 59 25 AD 94 69 F2 69 8E 4D
```

It always occurs at the same place after certain amount of correct captures. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my version if libpcap?

```
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libpcap.dylib
/usr/lib/libpcap.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Comment: This could have no meaning, but interpretting the bytes around your extra byte as 7-bit ascii yields `LC$EncW2w$=UHA` where the `E` is your extra byte.

Comment: "Is it possible that there is something wrong with my version if libpcap?"?  That's the system libpcap; if you got Wireshark from wireshark.org (rather than MacPorts), it also uses the system libpcap.

Comment: Are you capturing from a Wi-Fi interface?  If so, then what does System Profiler/System Report/whatever say the adapter is (Broadcom, Atheros, or something else), what does Wireshark report as the header after the Frame header (Radiotap?), and if it's Radiotap does it have the "Data Pad" flag bit set or not?

Comment: I'm using Wi-Fi (en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500). The interface is Broadcom BCM43xx. I'm afraid I don't understand your question about "Radiotap". I didn't see it anywhere.